# Java script not call a function on changing the value of a input field

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, bootstrap-4

I have bootstrap modal form with multiple input. One input field which contains the name of states and show the corresponding region on another field. The moments I change the value of state field the value of region should be changed.it is not working with my code,what is wrong with tis htlml code is

```
<div class="col-md-4 form-group"style="padding-right:0px;" >
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Region" >State</label>
    <?php 
      $sql="select rid,statename,region from tblregion order by statename";
      $stmt=$dbh->prepare($sql);
      $stmt->execute();
      $arrstate=$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    ?>
    <select class="form-control" name="state" id="state" >
      <option value="<?php echo htmlentities($result->state);?>"><?php echo htmlentities($result->statename);?></option>
      <?php
        foreach($arrstate as $state){
          ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $state['rid']?>"><?php echo $state['statename']?></option>
          <?php
        }
      ?>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-2 form-group" style="padding-left:0px;">
  <label for="Region" >Region</label>
  <select class="form-control" name="" id="region" readonly>
    <option><?php echo htmlentities($result->region);?></option>
  </select>
</div>
```

The CODE FOR JAVA SCRIPT is

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#state').change(function(){
      alert("hello);
      var rid=jQuery(this).val();

      jQuery.ajax({
        type:'post',
        url:'get_data.php',
        data:'id='+rid,
        success: function(result) {
          jQuery('#region').html(result); 
          //alert(result);
        }
      }); 
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: @Unmitigated That may be the reason but if i use the alert function (jquery code third line)after the change in value ,it should call the function  and message hello should appear.But it is not happening

Answer (score 1):

```
<select class="form-control" name="state" id="state" onchange="onStateChange(this.value)">
  ...
</select>

<script>
  function onStateChange(rid) {
    alert("hello");
    jQuery.ajax({
      type: "post",
      url: "get_data.php",
      data: { id: rid  },
      dataType: "json"
      success: function (result) {
        ...
      },
    });
  }
</script>
```

I want this helps you.

Comment: Thnx for your answer .In alert function if is use  Alert('rid') ,it should display the value of rid  but it is not showing

Comment: sorry. i want you to check my answer again. If it helps you, I wish you to check my answer as a solution. 

Comment: it is calling alert(hello)  function  buty if i use variable rid it is not calling

Comment: var rid = jQuery("#state").val();
alert(rid);   <-   Isn't it working?

Comment: it is not working.Will you please update the code where the I'd of state field will display on message on change

Comment: New code is also not working for you?
well, did you check state select html elements after php code rendering?

Comment: Still not working.This form is a modal select element is correct.